# Android check for valid video file

Tags: android

How to check a video file is valid or not without checking its extension(.mp3 or .3gp etc). Means how to check the video file on SD card is supported by device or not?

Is there any api to validate video file in android 4.0 and above?

**My Scenario:** I am playing video on VideoView after downloading it and play it from local SD card after download success. Next time when a request for same video, then checks in SD card, if found then start playing it(No download in this case). But sometimes network error or app kill interrupt the downloading(in this case the video file is not completely downloaded) so the downloaded file is corrupted and VideoView is unable to play this file. So how to detect this corrupted file.

Answer (score 14):

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
 MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
 retriever.setDataSource(context, Uri.fromFile(fileToTest));

 String hasVideo = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_HAS_VIDEO);
 boolean isVideo = "yes".equals(hasVideo);
```

Comment: setDataSource often throws `java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed` exception. For example if something is wrong with the path or with the file. For example file is empty (0 bytes) or broken. And basically you will have a crash.

Comment: @NoumanCh,  why don't add try catch, if exception is thrown, return false.

Comment: Don't forget to close the `MediaMetadataRetriever`

Answer (score 2):

@Alex had given right answer but still some problems are there as like @Kirill mention in comment that setDataSource often throws `java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed` exception. So Here is the function check for valid video file

```
private boolean videoFileIsCorrupted(String path){

    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(myContext, Uri.parse(path));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
     }

String hasVideo = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_HAS_VIDEO);
return "yes".equals(hasVideo);
}
```

Comment: `return "yes".equals(hasVideo);`. Does it seriously return "yes"? Thats crazy haha

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be useful, The method is an older one that i used for other purpose just modified a bit for your use, Try it ,May work

```
private void checkAndLoadFile(
        File currentFile) {
            String path = currentFile.getAbsolutePath();
    String extension = Utility.getExtension(path);
    MimeTypeMap mimeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();

    if(mimeMap.hasExtension(extension))
    {
        String mimeType = mimeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

        Intent viewFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        viewFile.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(currentFile), mimeType);

        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> apps = 
                pm.queryIntentActivities(viewFile, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        if (apps.size() > 0)
            startActivity(viewFile); //This video is supported and there are apps installed in this device to open the video
        else
            showAsNotSupported();
    } else
        showAsNotSupported();
}
```

Comment: Not working. It will just check the number of installed app for video

Comment: Did you pass the video file as argument

Comment: Its working fine for me, I just added the startactivity line check that